# Sorted drop-down of db list

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In the SQL-Developer there is a quick-access drop-down for the databases on the top right corner.

Apparently as a usability feature the recently uses databases are listed on top instead of alphabetically. After a while using diffent databases, I have no clue where my database is and would rather have a strictly alphabetically sorted list.

Is there any way to achieve this?